# stm32 multiple channel with different sampling rate

Tags: stm32, sampling, dma, adc, cubemx

I am working on project that which I need to employ two adc channels with different sampling rates over STM32F4x. The first channel where I need to monitor DC voltage (Vbat) with minimum sampling rate. While, the other channel I will use to pick up ECK with sampling rate about 1Khz. I have a problem with the CPU load which I am intending to solve using the DMA.

My problem is that I need only DMA for the ADC channel while the I dont it for monitoring the VBAT. How I will be able to use 2 channels of ADC with different sampling rates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the f4 UC have  more than one ADC converter. Just use one for the Vbat  and the second one for the high frequency  monitoring.

Another option is to start injected conversion for the Vbat - what the injected conversion is - read the Reference Manual

Comment: It has onr ADC.

Comment: So you should unveil the model to do not waste our time.

Comment: The model is STM32F407

Comment: @user9512877 I have amended my answer. Use regular conversions for the fast conversions, injected for the Vbat.

Comment: @user9512877 Just checked/ STM32F407 has 3 separate ADC converters. Did you read any documentation of your micro?

Comment: Using same sampling rate to convert both channels will be the easy choice but leak to much memory. Is there any HW option that enable me to physically open the dma for an ADC channel and read the other channel on request?

Comment: Did you read what I wrote - **injected conversions**. Open the Reference Manual are learn how to use them.

Comment: Done, I configured an injected conversion channel using cubemx. I mapped the conversion API (polling method) over a 500ms task while the regular channels are working over DMA. Everything works fine.

Thank you.

Comment: @user9512877 so chose my answer as the correct one. That is the way how the Stack Overflow works